# Почему в редакторе показывает другое а в эмуляторе совсем другое?

Tags: android, android-studio, эмулятор, экран, android-emulator

Интересный случай. Привязки сделаны а результат странный. 
С чем это связано и как можно исправить эту ситуацию? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

................................................................

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="160dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="368dp"
        android:text="Hello World"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="92dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="92dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="508dp"
        android:text="CheckBox"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Покажите что в разметке получилось (т.е. xml файл)

Comment: https://my-files.ru/oqqy1q  вот xml файл.

Comment: Я по незнакомым ссылкам не хожу) Добавьте разметку текстом прямо в вопрос)

Comment: ну ладно, раз так вам удобнее

Comment: Неплохо бы обрезать скриншот, а то там полезного меньше половины всей площади.

Comment: обрезал, что дальше? :)

Comment: У вас видимо экран эмулятора и превью разные. Располагаете элементы в т.ч. друг относительно друга, а не только относительно границ экрана

Comment: У кнопки отступ сверху, а у чекбокса снизу - при разных размерах экрана будет разным и их положение относительно друг друга. Плюс на превью нет заголовка и статус бара - это тоже сдвигает положение кнопки.

Comment: Первую часть вашего ответа я понял, изменил привязку чекбокса, теперь привязка сверху и результат вышел правильный. По ходу разумнее всего сразу сделать привязки компонентов одинаковыми или просто  привязать друг другу. С этим я разобрался.

Comment: а как это сделать? "на превью нет заголовка и статус бара - это тоже сдвигает положение кнопки."